# Why Array.push() changes elements in DOM, but simple value addition does not?

Tags: angular

When I use `Array.push()` in my code, it updates the `<li>` element in DOM, but when I want to update a number data type, it does not updates the `<p>` element. Why is that and how can I "force" update the `<p>` element if I want?

**api.ts**

```
export let value = 1;
export let array = [2,3,4,5,6];
```

**My component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { value, array } from './api';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <p>{{ val }}</p>
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of arr">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="addVal()">Add 1 to val</button>
    <button (click)="addArr()">Add 1 to arr</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  val = value;
  arr = array;

  addVal() {
    value += 1;

    console.log(value);
  }

  addArr() {
    array.push(7);
  }

}
```

[Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/nuXEXmqcNhSUgfk07wk7?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is a primitive (`number` like `string` and `boolean`) and is passed by value (copy)
An array is an object and is passed by reference (same instance)

Therefore

```
val = value;
```

is a one-time action and does **not** establish a connection between these two.

Therefore you'd need to change `addValue`

```
  addVal() {
    val += 1;

    console.log(value);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not refering to the correct fields.
It should be:

```
 addVal() {
    this.val += 1;

    console.log(value);
  }

  addArr() {
    this.arr.push(7);
  }
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/sHUQKc7MrEzCi4qxxtBp?p=preview

Note: What Günter said is absolutely true, numbers are **immutable** in js. I assumed you weren't wondering that issue.